# jQuery Equivalent to getElementbyName not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to create a hidden element and I want to use the value of the hidden element as a condition for if statement.

```
 var x = document.createElement('input');
        x.type = 'hidden';
        x.value = "Success";
        x.name = "eventName";
        console.log($("input[name='eventName']".value));
```

In another method,

```
if ($("input[name='eventName']".value) == "Success") 
{
   ---------------
}
```

$("input[name='eventName']".value) is returning 'undefined'.I want to get the  hidden element value in if statement.

Please help!thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$(selector/element)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) returns a jQuery object so you need to call the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method

```
if ($("input[name='eventName']").val() == "Success") 
{
   ---------------
}
```

In your case you are calling `"input[name='eventName']".value`, ie you are trying to access the `value` property of a string `input[name='eventName']` which is undefined and then is passing that to `jQuery`.

---

Also your `console.log($("input[name='eventName']".value));` won't print the value even if you corrected the syntax to `console.log($("input[name='eventName']").value);`, because since you are using a selector to find the element and you have not added the newly created element to the dom the selector engine won't be able to find the element.

You can either pass the dom element reference you created like

```
console.log($(x).value);
```

or you can run that particular script after the element `x` is added to the dom.

Comment: Thanks for this!when the element will be added to DOM?

Comment: I have tried ur solution but it is not working ...Not sure if i miss something...http://jsfiddle.net/khzodfcn/

Comment: It works but ($("input[name='eventName']").val() == "Success") still returns undefined.

Comment: because you haven't added the element to the dom yet... also the name is `EventName` not `eventName` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/khzodfcn/2/

Comment: It works but ($("input[name='eventName']").val() == "Success") still returns undefined.Let me explain clear on what am i doing.I am trying to create a hidden element inside a method.Then I am trying to access the value of the hidden element from a different method which is totally outside the scope of the hidden element creation method.But the methods will be  consecutively executed while a page header is being loaded.

Comment: @user3806955 sorry mate.. unless the hidden element you are created is not added to the dom... the jQuery selector will fail... in the above fiddle `$(x).appendTo('body');` adds the dom element referenced by `x` to the `body` element that is why the `input[name='EventName']` is working in the fiddle... if you could recreate the issue in the fiddle we could try to help... else there nothing more can be done

Comment: thanks!....all good now...sorry,I have seen ur comment reg dom only after adding my previous comment....